# Boost.Python exposing class using global pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, game-development, boost-python

I am writting a game in C++ to which I want to add some dynamically loaded Python scripts. There is a global service called GameEngine, which is a global unique_ptr. I can use it from any place of the code to tell the game that something happened. To simplify:

```
inline std::unique_ptr<class Game> GameEngine;
    
class Game
{
public:
    void printHello() { std::cout<<"Hello World"<<std::endl; }
};
```

Later I initialize the pointer with:

```
GameEngine = std::make_unique<Game>();
```

I want to be able to notify game about events from my Python scripts, so I thought I will make some GameWrapper:

```
class GameWrapper
{
public:
    void printHello() { GameEngine->printHello(); }
};
```

And exposed that class like:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyGameModule)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<GameWrapper>("GameWrapper")
        .def("printHello", &GameWrapper::printHello)
        ;
}
```

And my Python script:

```
from MyGameModule import *

class Script():
    def execute(self):
        GameWrapper().printHello()
```

Then I want to call that script when it's needed from C++ by:

```
Py_Initialize();
auto module = python::import("MyGameModule");
auto script = module.attr("Script")();
script.attr("execute")();
```

But unfortunately, it crashes because pointer is null when called from Python. This design is based on Ron Penton MUD game programming book, but he used SWIG there (not 100% understandable for me in fact), and I decided to try with Boost.Python. Is there any way to make this pointer viable and impact already running game from loaded Python scripts?

Comment: Can you export the pointer as a global with `boost::python::scope().attr` ?